# format data with year and moth presence javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this kind of json object

```
[  {
    "camera_name": "Bolands Mills Arup",
    "exid": "bolands-mills-arup",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:06:55+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-12-24T23:33:23+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "04",
        "08",
        "09",
        "10",
        "02",
        "06",
        "03",
        "11",
        "12",
        "01",
        "07",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "04",
        "07",
        "10",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "08",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "10",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "09",
        "04",
        "07",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12",
        "11"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "02",
        "03",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "03",
        "08",
        "10",
        "02",
        "04",
        "05",
        "06",
        "07",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "04",
        "07",
        "09",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "10",
        "11",
        "05",
        "06",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And I have a parameter with the name of the year, whom value can be 2015 to 2019. What I am trying to do is create a method which will formate this data with year and months values.

I have this pattern of months as

```
 let months_chars = {
    "01":"jan", 
    "02":"feb", 
    "03":"mar",
    "04":"apr",
    "05":"may",
    "06":"jun",
    "07":"jul",
    "08":"aug",
    "09":"sep",
    "10":"oct",
    "11":"nov",
    "12":"dec"
  }
```

Year value is being selected by the user, For example, if the user will select 2016 then the lower data will look like this.

```
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "jan": 0,
    "feb": 1,
    "mar": 1,
    "apr": 0,
    "may", 1,
    ...
    "dec": 0
  }
```

It will go through the years present values if the month is present then it will add months chars and place 1 in front, if not then still place a month and place 0 in front.

Any help would be thankful, I have reached this far with that,

```
  let months_chars = {
    "01":"jan", 
    "02":"feb", 
    "03":"mar",
    "04":"apr",
    "05":"may",
    "06":"jun",
    "07":"jul",
    "08":"aug",
    "09":"sep",
    "10":"oct",
    "11":"nov",
    "12":"dec"
  }
  let year = this.year;

  let formatedData =
    data.map((camera) => {
      let present_months = data["years"][`${year}`]

    });
```

Further, I am unable to format the data as required.

Comment: How do we know which object will be selected when the user chooses a year? Because both objects contain a 2016 object, for instance

Comment: It will format both objects, not only one.
if user select 2016 the same thing will happen with both objects.

Comment: A year is an option and it will loop through all objects for a year. I just put the one object in result the question was getting long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Use map() to loop over each object, and loop over each months_chars to check if the years includes the key, and return 1 if true and 0 if false:

```js
const cameras = [{
    "camera_name": "Bolands Mills Arup",
    "exid": "bolands-mills-arup",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:06:55+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-12-24T23:33:23+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "04",
        "08",
        "09",
        "10",
        "02",
        "06",
        "03",
        "11",
        "12",
        "01",
        "07",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "04",
        "07",
        "10",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "08",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "05",
        "06",
        "10",
        "11",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "09",
        "04",
        "07",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "camera_name": "Walls Demo",
    "exid": "central-bank-fusion",
    "latest_snapshot_date": "2019-05-30T07:07:02+01:00",
    "oldest_snapshot_date": "2015-11-08T16:30:48+00:00",
    "years": {
      "2015": [
        "12",
        "11"
      ],
      "2016": [
        "02",
        "03",
        "05"
      ],
      "2017": [
        "03",
        "08",
        "10",
        "02",
        "04",
        "05",
        "06",
        "07",
        "09",
        "11",
        "01",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2018": [
        "03",
        "04",
        "07",
        "09",
        "01",
        "02",
        "08",
        "10",
        "11",
        "05",
        "06",
        "11",
        "12"
      ],
      "2019": [
        "01",
        "02",
        "03",
        "04",
        "05"
      ]
    }
  }
]

let months_chars = {
  "01": "jan",
  "02": "feb",
  "03": "mar",
  "04": "apr",
  "05": "may",
  "06": "jun",
  "07": "jul",
  "08": "aug",
  "09": "sep",
  "10": "oct",
  "11": "nov",
  "12": "dec"
}

var input = 2016
var obj = cameras.map(({years, ...obj}) => {
  var months = years[input]
  for(var i in months_chars) {
    months.includes(i) ? obj[months_chars[i]] = 1 : obj[months_chars[i]] = 0
  }
  return obj
  
})

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: It does, you might not be able to use the prompt, so i'll hardcode a variable.

Comment: Thanks Kobe. You are a great player. :D

Comment: No problem. If you need any other help, feel free to ask.

Comment: I am going to post the same question like this can you help?

Comment: Sure what's the issue?